# what design pattern for building this complex object

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I have to create an itinerary object which is essentially made of other components.

These components need to be added in a particular order. I need to make sure when things are added out of order, an exception/error needs to be thrown.

Quick walkthrough:

```
Itinerary Build-itinerary():

- AddSegment()
- AddBaggagePolicy()
- AddMisc()

Segment AddSegment(...)

- add departure airport
- add arrival airport
- add departure time
- add arrival time
- add duration (total duration)
- add airline
```

where airport and airline are object types.

Once segments are done, I need to consolidate the segments to yield starting departure to final arrival destination (since there can be multiple hop points from one point to other).

What kind of a pattern can I refer to building this itinerary ?

Comment: Is this being closed because it's a design question ?

Comment: Your not building Itinerary ..  You created the object, add make many calls like depart(), arrive() etc on it.   The sequence between them should not matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like it isn't specific enough.  At first glance, I might characterise this as a "builder pattern".  Many (but not all!) design patterns in Java are workarounds for lack of language features.

In fact, your design there is a code smell, you should not have an apparently arbitrary ordered sequence of steps to construct an object. Instead, define the data, and pass that into the object.

If you must build your object like this, then I would ensure that any code that does this is unit tested using a mock that supports the record and playback style of mocking. (So-called "strict mocks".

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Can you elaborate a bit on code smell and instead, defining data and pass that into the object.

Comment: @brainydexter: I would prefer something like .addSegment(departureAirport, depatureTime, arrivalAirport, arrivalTime, duration, airline), and make addSegment itself responsible for doing whatever magic in whatever order that it needs to do it in to get it all working correctly. That abstracts the implementation detail so that the caller doesn't need to think about it.

Comment: Does this make sense ? http://pastebin.com/YzYMTBg3 (I've hardcoded those names and parameters in addXXX(...), but that would come through the data passed in.

Comment: @brainydexter: That makes sense, but could be improved. For example, does it really make sense to 'add' an arrival time to a segment?  What happens when you add two arrival times to the same segment?  That said, as a pattern you're implementing it well.  I just question the need to use the pattern. :) (Then again, I'm not a typical Java programmer).

Comment: I agree with the comment on "add".  Unless you can add multiples the these should be "set" IMO.

Answer (score 2):

And I am not good with design patterns at all: I would start with a Builder Pattern and try to validate each component if it has been added or not. At least this would be my start point : a Builder or a private static inner class.

Answer (score 2):

Try using the Builder Pattern. Also you could look for other variants in the Creational Patterns category.

If you're new to design patterns then take a look at "Head First Design Patterns" - its in google books (I dont know if complete or preview though...)

have fun :)

Answer (score 1):

When I hear the words "building" and "order" then first design pattern that comes to mind is Builder. If you new to Design Patterns then I would recommend you to read "Applied Java Patterns".

Answer (score 0):

Cannot agree with @Arafangion, I belive that ordering of some procedure invocations is sometimes necessary. I would recommend looking into a Factory Method design pattern, from what I remember there is a nice example in [Head First Design Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596007124) book when preparing pizza stuff :)

Comment: While I agree that sometimes it is necessary, I would hardly claim that it is necessary in this case - and even if it were necessary, I would hardly claim that it's ideal.